Setting class with class binding through pipe
Having a problem with setting a class via custom pipe that I wrote.
I use signal Store that I map over to check if the value is matched with id in the store and if the condition is true, then if it's true return one class, if not then return different class.
Store:
const initialState: LightboxState = {
  isActive: [
    { id: 'singleSided', status: false },
    { id: 'doubleSided', status: false },
    { id: 'illuminated', status: false },
    { id: 'notIlluminated', status: false },
    { id: 'standing', status: false },
    { id: 'hanging', status: false },
  ],

Pipe:
@Pipe({
  name: 'setClass',
  standalone: true,
  pure: false,
})

export class setClassPipe implements PipeTransform {
  private store = inject(LightboxStore);

  transform(value: string) {
    this.store.isActive().map((id) => {
      console.log(id.id);
      if (value === id.id && id.status === true) {
        console.log(id.status);
        return 'btn-active';
      }
      console.log(id.status);
      return 'btn-not-active';
    });
  }
}

template:
<button
  type="button"
  class="shadow"
  (click)="changeStatus('singleSided', 'doubleSided')"
  [class]="'singleSided' | setClass"
>
  JEDNOSTRONNY
</button>

The function reads properly value, id.id and id.status, but does not set any kind of class to the buttons even if initially it's false

It appears that I was not returning the value properly.
This works properly:
  helper = '';

  transform(value: string) {

    this.store.isActive().map((id) => {
      if (value === id.id && id.status) this.helper = 'btn-active';
      if (value === id.id && !id.status) this.helper = 'btn-not-active';
    });
    return this.helper;
  }

